# Prevent scrolling but allow swipe event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm working on a mobile version of a webpage, and one of the features we have is a slide out sidebar. On my Android device, when the sdiebar is visible it is still possible to scroll the background using the part of the body that's still visible. To solve this, I disable scrolling on the page using:

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

When the sidebar is opened, and then unbind it when the sidebar is closed.

Recently I wanted to try and add in the ability to swipe and close the sidebar. Using jQuery Mobile functionality, I subscribed tot he `swipeleft` event like so:

```
$(document).on("swipeleft", swipeLeftHandler);
function swipeLeftHandler(event) {
    if (isSidebarOpen()) {
        toggleSidebar();
    }
}
```

I'm intentionally subscribing to the entire page since it doesn't matter where they swipe. This doesn't work when I'm preventing touchmove, but does when I remove that code. Obviously the downside to that is that a user can still scroll the main page behind the sidebar.

To implement the sidebar, I'm using the JQuery slide event and have it inside a div that's floating to the left and has a fixed position.

Is there any way I could disable scrolling but still allow for the `swipeleft` event to work?

Comment: Have you tried overflow hidden on the scrollable region when the navigation window is opened?

Comment: Originally I had which disabled scrolling properly when using a desktop browser but not a phone (they could still scroll when the sidebar reached the upper or lower limits.) However I started using iScroll on the sidebar which wouldn't have this problem, so I'll try that again and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Found this, and added overflow hidden when opened http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/m1oksz3v/

Comment: Cheers, that seems to work great. Originally I had "overflow-x: scroll" on the sidebar, and even if I did "overflow: hidden" on the body, scrolling to the upper or lower bounds of the sidebar still scrolled the body which resulted in strange behaviour. Now I've chagned to using iScroll this doesn't happen anymore so I can now use "overflow: hidden" to disable scrolling again.

Comment: Just an observation, for testing purposes I set "overflow: hidden" to the body class when opening the sidebar but didn't remove it when closing the sidebar. I'm still able to scroll when the sidebar is closed but not open (albeit it's jumpy); not sure why that is but it's working how I want it to since I'll re-enable scrolling when the sidebar is closed. It's an MVC5 project that also utilised Bootstrap, so there's probably something weird going on there.